# Операторы перемещения и копирования в одном классе, основанные на copy-swap идиоме

Tags: c++, классы

В классе есть два перегруженных оператора, перемещения и копирования:

```
MyClass& operator=(MyClass other) // other не через ссылку, т. к. используется copy-swap идиома
MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other)
```

Строка `std::move(object)` влечет за собой ошибку компиляции, т. к. компилятор не знает, какой из методов выше вызывать, ведь объект можно передать как `rvalue` в любой. Возможно ли это исправить, по-прежнему используя `copy-swap` идиому?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вторую перегрузку можно просто выкинуть, первой достаточно.

Еще есть вариант заменить параметр первой перегрузки на `const MyClass &other`, и внутри делать копию в локальную переменную.